# Like Button og: image and og:title not being recognised

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

When using the like button, the defined og:image and og:title do not show on facebook page.

Link to example .. It's the like button at bottom of the article and not the one at the top of the page:  http://www.nflfc.co.uk/main.php?articleId=221&pageId=3&teamId=3

Using the linter I get the following info which all points to everything being ok but no joy...

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nflfc.co.uk%2Fmain.php%3FarticleId%3D221%26pageId%3D3%26teamId%3D3

Any help to point me in the right direction into what I am doing wrong will be much appreciated.

Adi

---

Thankyou for replying so quickly.  I think you are correct in the facebook cache being regional, as I have just had an overseas friend test and it worked fine for him too.

I'm concerned how I am writing my code now though with this cache.....

```
<?php
$url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>Nottingham Forest Ladies Football Club - <?php echo $row_pageLayoutSelection['linkTitle']; ?></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta property="og:title" content="NFLFC : <?php echo $row_article2['articleTitle']; ?>" />
<meta property="og:type" content="sports_team" />
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo $url; ?>" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.nflfc.co.uk/images/news/<?php echo $row_article2['articleId']; ?>_154x85.jpg" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="NFLFC : <?php echo $row_article2['articleTitle']; ?>" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="xxxxxxx"/>
<meta property="fb:admins" content="xxxxxxx" />
```

Will this dynamic data for individual database articles be ok or will I encounter Facebook cache issue do you think?

Thanks again for your help with this, greatly appreciated.

Adi

Answer (score 4):

Facebook caches data when you first add like button to your page. This caches might be regional not sure about that, but it takes 24hr to remove caches sometimes. So make a working template for your like button headers and use them all the time, if lint shows its ok then it ll be ok.

(Note:try to like the page from https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ this might fix it, just a superstition)

when i liked the post,

shows this image

http://www.nflfc.co.uk/images/news/221_154x85.jpg

and this info on profile

NFLFC : Forest Girls 8 v 0 Wollaton Hall
It was Wollaton who created the first chance causing Natalie to pull off a good save, but after 7 minutes Jessica Munn put Forest ahead with a clinical finish. Forest without being fluent created other opportunities, but it was a poor clearance by the keeper which led to Leia Ward increasing the lea...

Answer (score 1):

The caching could be true. i had the problem with a page, renamed the page and all was ok for the new page. Now i tried loading this old page once again to check and it integrated the image just fine. So there IS caching and caching is temporary.

But now I have the problem with a brand new page that shouldn't be cached yet.
Very frustrating.

Image is retrieved from MySQL blob field by asp script. the debugger shows the image and gives no error but the button on the page doesn't take the image.

Page: http://www.ffkama.be/html/2_agenda_detail.asp?ps=id51

Image URL: http://www.ffkama.be/root/imager_ag.asp?id=51

Suggestion for FB devs, after a successful debug use on the page, purge cache or cache the debugged page

UPDATE: I forgot the code in the HEAD TAG :( One thing is sure, without the 'prefix="og: h t tp://ogp.me/ns# fb: ht tp://ogp.me/ns/fb# website: h t tp://ogp.me/ns/website#"' in the HEAD Tag, the debugger doesn't give an arror and the image shows up in the dubugger but the image won't show up on your page. Then the page is cached and there are only 2 solutions: 1. rename the page 2. wait several days for the cache to expire

Answer (score 0):

I had a white .png that was not showing up because the background of facebook is white of course. So I changed my og:image to a black logo but it wouldn't refreshed the cached .png. Just simply going to this link fixed it. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your image size:
221_154x85.jpg is supposed to be a 154x85 pixes image, right?

According to the debugger page:
*All the images referenced by og:image should be at least 200px in both dimensions. Please check all the images with tag og:image in the given url and ensure that it meets the recommended specification.*

hope it'll help