# Facebook - No image shown for Like button to my Facebook Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have followed the official steps from Facebook to create my Like button, pointing to my Facebook page. But when clicking on the Like button to post to my Facebook wall, there is not photo being shown.

I have used the suggested meta tags, still no hope. Any advice is appreciated!

Edited:
The facebook popup is: [image]

And have used the following meta tags:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="sample title" />
<meta property="og:type" content="product" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.facebook.com/mypagename" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.mydomain.com/images/productimage.jpg" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="sitename" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="123456789" />
```

Another example of this issue, when I use this:
    https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/
to generate the Like button, for
1. https://www.facebook.com/google - I will see the all the information like title, URL, description, and the image.
2. https://www.facebook.com/KFC - There isn't any information being displayed. This is exactly the same issue as I am facing.

Please advice.

regards

Comment: you need to post screenshots or something to start with. at this point, you haven't given us enough to help you.

Comment: it might be cache related? see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7507387/like-button-og-image-and-ogtitle-not-being-recognised

Comment: My facebook page is just a page, I have not created an app for it, would this be an issue? :)

Comment: updated the question again, the same thing happen to https://www.facebook.com/kfc, but https://www.facebook.com/google works.

Answer (score 0):

For Facebook pages, you should use the Like Box plugin (as opposed to the Like plugin) as it is designed specifically for liking pages.  It has more features aimed specifically for pages.  See:  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

Comment: not really, found out that it could be a little bug from FB. Explanation: 1. https://www.facebook.com/abcdefg - doesnt' work, 2. https://www.facebook.com/abcdefg/ - works, 3. https://www.facebook.com/abcdefgdummystring - works. It seems like the page name is too short or something. Well, it works for all now.

Comment: Odd, using the Like Box I don't seem to have the same issue you're having. BTW, none of your links are real pages or they are hidden/private.  This is probably why the like box plugin is not working for you. Can you create a jsfiddle for us to look at and might help us understand what your issue is.

Comment: Here's a sample fiddle with a short name and a long name working correctly.  http://jsfiddle.net/dmcs/3D2GD/14/