# I'm trying to add a facebook recommend button to a product page

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, facebook

I've already gone to the facebook developers page about this, and almost everything works when I use the resource they give me, which only requires that I provide the URL to be liked before generating the code. The problem is that it takes the website's image instead of the product's image, and I was wondering if someone knew how to edit or add to the code Facebook Dvelopers gave me so that I can choose the image that will appear on everyone's facebook walls when they choose to share. Here's the inframe code:

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.4-hmall.org%2FProduct%2Fclubsupplies-bags-totes%2FBAG2.aspx&amp;width&amp;layout=standard&amp;action=recommend&amp;show_faces=true&amp;share=true&amp;height=80" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure this is what you are looking for but it sounds like it might be.

Try using the FB Image Meta Tag on your page

```
 <meta property="og:image" content="img/facebook.png"/>
```

here is a good article about all the FB meta tag stuff

http://davidwalsh.name/facebook-meta-tags

Comment: My share button works perfectly now, but the like and recommend ones are still grabbing the wrong image.

Comment: This could be a caching issue they go into an indept discussion on this tread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7507387/like-button-og-image-and-ogtitle-not-being-recognised

Comment: if you knew how to make it so that I would only add a share button, that would also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use facebook's `og:image` meta tag. If it does not work check that facebook has not already cached the header image before you added meta data. Put your URL into this site and facebook will help you out:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug